# Check for annotation present on superclass field

Tags: grails, reflection, groovy, metaprogramming

I have problems to check if a persistent property in grails has an specific annotation for **fields that belong to superclass** ... ane then get it's name and value.

I am getting the persistence properties as:

```
GrailsDomainClassProperty[] persistentProperties = new DefaultGrailsDomainClass(entityClass).getPersistentProperties();
```

That works great ... but later i found that getDeclaredFields only retrieves the actual class fields (not superclass) and things starts to look not very Groovy.

Is there a prefered Groovy way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you should use this code for all super classes. The same will be for children classes.